# Debugging a c-extension in python

Tags: c, python-2.7, gdb, coredump, python-c-api

I run [bayesopt](http://rmcantin.bitbucket.org/html/) with python bindings. So I have a `bayesopt.so` that I import from python (a C-extension).

When I run it, it core dumps. I want to load this core dump in gdb to see what the issue is. How can I do this? Or get information on it?

I tried to load gdb on it, but of course it asks for a binary which I don't have since it's a `.so`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to run gdb on python, ie: `gdb -ex r --args python myscript.py`. There's some helpful tips in the python wiki: https://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb